# A sufficient condition for complete regularity?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

If $X$ is a completely regular space, then the zero-set-neighborhoods of points form a neighborhood basis. Does the converse hold for Hausdorff spaces?I don't guess so.

Comment: What's a zero-set-neighborhood of a point?

Comment: according to  the book by Gillman and Jerison this is a set of the form $Z(f):=\{x\in X: f(x)=0\}$ such that the given point $x_0$ belongs to the interior of $Z(f)$.

Comment: I  think that the converse might  hold for completely Hausdorff spaces.

Comment: I think that under the basic hypothesis  of the problem here both  definitions   for `completely Hausdorffian'  are automatically satisfied  (either there exist disjoint closed neighborhoods separating $x$ and $y$ or, more strongly,  there is a continuous function $f$ with $f(x)=0$ and $f(y)=0$).